# why using useQuery() destroys next auth session on refreshing the browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth, trpc.io

Using T3 Stack (Nextjs, Typescript, TRPC, Prisma, Planetscale mysql database)

When ever I use this const { data: emails } = api.email.getAll.useQuery(); and fetch the emails in my authorised page, I can see all the details but looks like whenever I refresh my browser I'm unauthenticated for some reason. I added email router file as well for better understanding

Please need help in this

**Index.tsx**

```
import { type NextPage } from "next";
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Styles from "~/styles/home.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";
import { useState } from "react";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { data: sessionData } = useSession();
  return <>{sessionData ? <Authx /> : <Guest />}</>;
};

export default Home;

const Authx: React.FC = () => {
  const { data: sessionData } = useSession();
  const { data: emails } = api.email.getAll.useQuery();
  return (
    <div className={Styles.mainBody}>
      <h1 className="mb-6 text-3xl font-extrabold underline decoration-blue-600">
        Welcome to Authorised page!
      </h1>
      <h3 className="mt-2 text-lg font-bold">{sessionData?.user.name}</h3>
      <h3 className="mt-2 text-lg font-bold">{sessionData?.user.email}</h3>
      <button className={Styles.signoutBtn} onClick={() => void signOut()}>
        Sign Out
      </button>

      <div className="my-10">
        <h2 className="mb-6 text-2xl font-extrabold">
          Email Lists from normal user
        </h2>
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-2 text-lg font-medium">
          {emails?.map((email, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <p>{email.emailNames}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Guest: React.FC = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");

  const { mutate: subNewsletter } = api.email.subscribe.useMutation();

  const handleEmailSub = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className={Styles.mainBody}>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold underline decoration-blue-600">
        Welcome to Guest page!
      </h1>
      <Link href="/signin">
        <button className={Styles.signinBtn}>Sign In</button>
      </Link>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleEmailSub}>
          <input
            className={Styles.inputField}
            placeholder="Enter email address"
            type="email"
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className={Styles.subBtn}
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => subNewsletter({ emailNames: input })}
          >
            Subscribe
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

//! Down below code is for protected homepage,
//! everytime someone puts the hompage url will go to signin always
//! Uncomment if you think you need the feature

// export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }: any) => {
//   const session = await getSession({ req });

//   if (!session) {
//     return {
//       redirect: {
//         destination: "/signin",
//         permanent: false,
//       },
//     };
//   }

//   return {
//     props: { session },
//   };
// };
```

**router/email.ts**

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { createTRPCRouter, publicProcedure } from "~/server/api/trpc";

export const emailRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  getAll: publicProcedure.query(({ ctx }) => {
    return ctx.prisma.email.findMany();
  }),

  subscribe: publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({ emailNames: z.string() }))
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      return ctx.prisma.email.create({
        data: {
          emailNames: input.emailNames,
        },
      });
    }),
});
```

All good! Just user is unauthenticated after refreshing the web

It doesn't work when I add the useQuery() but it works without it perfectly